# Return User Full Name Instead of UserID in MVC Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to display a user's full name in my view instead of the `ID`. So in my

**modelView;**

```
public int UserId { get; set; }
```

but in my view I want to display full name like "Joe Doe"

Can somebody help me

Answer (score 0):

In your `modelView` add a string property called `FullName`,

**modelView;**

```
public string FullName {get;set;}
```

Then get your user by the `UserID` at the controller,

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    User User = DbContext.User.Where(x => x.UserID == something).FirstOrDefault(); // gets the user by ID
    modelView model= new modelView(); 
    model.FullName = User.Name + " " + User.LastName; // set Full name
    return View(model); // return model to razor
}
```

Hope helps,